# Asp.net MVC5 Bind with View

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Can Any Help me. when i am updating the Record i have the following issue occur.

> angular.js:12477 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `08/02/2016` to be
>   a date

Comment: I guess, you are assigning string vlaue `08/02/2016` to `type="date"` field.. it is expecting `date` object

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt

Comment: Thanks Sir. its working now

Comment: hi sir are you there